# select query - eliminate rows with duplicate column value on condition

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, subquery

I have a select query that ends up with results like:

```
ID     COMPLIANT
------------------
10         0
12         0
29         0
29         1
43         1
44         1
44         0
```

How can I get results without these duplicate ID rows, on the condition that if an ID has already been marked as COMPLIANT once (a 1 instead of a 0), the duplicate rows with COMPLIANT=0 do not appear? I'd want:

```
ID     COMPLIANT
------------------
10         0
12         0
29         1
43         1
44         1
```

Answer (score 3):

How about aggregation?

```
select id, max(complaint) as complaint
from t
group by id;
```

This returns one row per id.  If you can have multiple complaints -- and you want all of those -- than an alternative is:

```
select id, complaint
from t
where complaint = 1
union all
select id, complaint
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.complaint = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select id, max(complaint) 
from tablename
group by id;
```